# Get all numbers between two numbers

Tags: c#

I want to get all the numbers say from **0 - 10**.

So like

`if textbox1.text.contains(0 - 10)
    {
        messagebox.show("true");
    }`

etc.

I'm sorry if its a noob question. Im new to the language.

Thanks

Comment: are you trying to actually get a collection of the numbers between, or just checking if an input number is inside of the range?

Comment: Input number is inside the range.

Comment: "get all the numbers" - What do you mean by this?  That statement alone seems to mean "generate a collection of integers within a given range".  But then your example seems to mean "search a string to verify whether it contains all of the numbers within a given range".

Comment: You better give sample inputs and expected outputs

Answer (score 3):

I know others have already answered, but here's some neater code with explanations:

#### Here's how you could break this down into steps (a plan)

1. Determine what type of data you want (such as integers, fractions accurate to 2 decimal places, inaccurate fractions)
2. Determine the number represented by the text in the text box.
3. Determine if the number falls within the range

   1. Determine if the number is greater than or equal to the minimum value
   2. Determine if the number is less than or equal to the maximum value

#### Translate it into code

```
int number; //Use chosen data type here
if (int.TryParse(textbox1.text, out number)) //Check if text matches the data type, and put it in the number variable if it does.
{
    if (number >= 0 && number <= 10) //Check if the number is within the range
    { messagebox.show("true"); }
}
else
{
    //Optionally do something here (the text doesn't match the data type)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to work with integers...

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(textbox1.text) >= 0 && Convert.ToInt32(textbox1.text) <= 10)
{
    messagebox.show("true");
}
```

You'd probably want to do some kind of error checking or input control on the textbox to make sure it contains valid integers.

Comment: How about factoring out Convert.ToInt32(textbox1.text)?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this for working with integers:

```
IsBetween(int min, int max)
{
   if (Convert.ToInt32(textbox1.text) >= min 
        && Convert.ToInt32(textbox1.text) <= max)
   {
       messagebox.show("true");
   }
}
```